# Remove set of commas from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, regex

There are a set of commas in each columns and rows. I want to eliminate the commas before and after string.

eg: ,,,,,something, something,,,,,,,,,,,

I want to eliminate only the commas and the front and end of the string, not the real comma in between. Its almost in every rows and columns. I know this can be done by regx and replace functions in php.

But I want to make changes in the database itself. (New table without this unnecessary commas)

[image]

Comment: In your first row why are there commas left over in the `email` column? You should make a copy of this table before starting anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably need to trim the values in your database using an update query.

**The is for the name column only**

```
UPDATE `example_table` SET `name` = TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM `name`)
```

Disclaimer: **Please only use in a testing environment, I'm not responsible for any loss of data**

Comment: it will deleted every comma from name right? but i want to delete commas at the starting and ending of the string

Comment: it will delete the commas from the values in your name column (not the column name itself)